# Trouble restoring checkpointed TensorFlow net

Tags: tensorflow

I have built an auto encoder to "convert" the activations from `VGG19.relu4_1` into pixels. I use the new convenience functions in `tensorflow.contrib.layers` (as in TF 0.10rc0). The code is have similar layout as TensorFlow's CIFAR10 tutorial with a `train.py` that does the training and checkpoints the model to disk and one `eval.py` that polls for new checkpoints files and run inference on them.

My problem is that the evaluation is never as good as the training, neither in terms of the value of the loss function nor when I look at the output images (even when running on the same images as the training does). This makes me think it has something to do with the restore process.

When I look at the output from the training in TensorBoard it looks good (eventually) so I don't think there is anything wrong with my net per se.

My net looks like this:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.layers as contrib
bn_params = {                                                                             
    "is_training": is_training,
    "center": True,
    "scale": True
}                                                                                                                                                       

tensor = contrib.convolution2d_transpose(vgg_output, 64*4, 4,                               
    stride=2,
    normalizer_fn=contrib.batch_norm,
    normalizer_params=bn_params,
    scope="deconv1")                                                        
tensor = contrib.convolution2d_transpose(tensor, 64*2, 4,                               
    stride=2,
    normalizer_fn=contrib.batch_norm,
    normalizer_params=bn_params,
    scope="deconv2")
.
.
.
```

And in `train.py` I do this to save the checkpoint:

```
variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(mynet.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY)
variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())

with tf.control_dependencies([apply_gradient_op, variables_averages_op]):
    train_op = tf.no_op(name='train')

while training:
    # train (with batch normalization's is_training = True)
    if time_to_checkpoint:
        saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=step)
```

In `eval.py` I do this:

```
# run code that creates the net

variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(
                  mynet.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY)
saver = tf.train.Saver(variable_averages.variables_to_restore())

while polling:
    # sleep and check for new checkpoint files
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        init_local = tf.initialize_local_variables()
        sess.run([init, init_local])
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)

        # run inference (with batch normalization's is_training = False)
```

[image: The loss function]

The blue is the training loss, and the orange is the eval loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used the `tf.train.AdamOptimizer()` directly. During the optimization it didn't call the operations defined in `contrib.batch_norm` to calculate the running mean/variance of the input so the mean/variance was always 0.0/1.0.

The solution is to add a dependency to the `GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` collection. There already is a function defined in the `contrib` module that does this ([`optimize_loss()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#optimize_loss))

Comment: Thanks for solving. Am I the only one who feels this really should be well documented/fixed. I figured the `optimize_loss()` function was just a shortcut for optimizer.minimize(loss, step) as opposed to something that was necessary for other contrib.layers to work as advertised.